# macOS - partial admin account

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, administrator

I am one of team of front end developers working on Macs (Mojave) in a predominantly windows based company. The IT dept has limited knowledge of Macs and they have locked down the Macs quite a bit :-(

We need to be able to run MAMP (or similar) for front end dev work but MAMP requires admin rights to run a "helper" app which we don't have. Sudo is also blocked too naturally.

Is there a way to have partial admin rights? Obviously I can't try it out as it's locked.

Comment: Not a permissions expert myself. Could the IT dept install their RMM + AV (assuming its available) on the Mac, and then give you an admin account on it?

Comment: You can configure sudo to allow a user to run a certain command.

Comment: How would they feel if you hacked the mac to give you admin rights?

Comment: You can get parallels virtual machine app and run whatever version of macOS it it you need.

Comment: Thanks for your swift responses guys. 

RMM is remote monitoring & management and AV is anti virus I presume. Sorry, I'm just a front end dev, so had to look them up. Anyway, yes that's how they distribute software and stop us looking at sites we want to. They definitely do not want to give us any admin rights though.

Configuring sudo to allow a certain command sounds like it may be an option.

IT would definitely not like it if we hacked our Macs. I have a personal license for MAMP but if we do get it to work, I'm not even allowed to use that!